# Clearcase: how to copy/fork a file?

Tags: clearcase

In Clearcase, I want to copy (fork, split) a file while preserving its history. Something like `svn cp old.txt new.txt`. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you working with Base ClearCase or UCM ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't possible do fork a file in ClearCase.

If you refactor your code and split a file in two, one of them will appear as a new file and you will loose the information about who coded it. The annotate command will say the author of the lines are who splited it.

Comment: +1. That seems to be in agreement with my initial conclusions in my answer.

Comment: @vonc excuse me. You really say that. But I though a more direct and succinct answer would be better for the future readers. Thanks for all your help around here. You are one of the bests.

Answer (score 3):

UCM or not, you cannot duplicate easily the full history of a file.
The best way to isolate an history is still to create a branch in order to make new versions to that file without impacting the same file in the original branch.

Thinking 'svn cp' should be available in ClearCase might come from the fact that, in SVN, branches are directories, and a tool like **[cc2svn](http://code.google.com/p/cc2svn/)** will actually replicate ClearCase branches using '`svn cp`'.

But since, with ClearCase, branches are first-class citizen, it is best to reason in term of branch than in term of copy/fork.

From the main page of cc2svn:

> There is a difference in creating the branches in ClearCase and SVN:
>
> - SVN copies all files from parent branch to the target like: `svn cp branches/main branches/dev_branch`
> - ClearCase creates the actual branch for file upon checkout operation only.

Comment: I don't want to branch the file. I want two copies of it. I'm refactoring some of the code to other file and don't want to loose its history.

Comment: @neves: my point is: copy in svn (which keeps the history) is very different than the copy in ClearCase (which doesn't keep the history and create a different object entirely). The right way to reason with ClearCase is in branch, as opposed to SVN where '`cp`' is the way to create everything (branch, tag, copies...).

Comment: @neves: You can copy a single file, but you won't get its full history. In a branch however, the name of the file won't change, and you will still benefit from its full history.

Comment: Cam I create a branch of the file in the same directory, rename it and then work with the two files? Will The two files have local copies every time someone create a view?

Comment: "in the same directory"? no. You need two different views, the second one with a config spec including a selection rule like `element /path/to/file /main/LATEST -mkbranch aBranch` in order to branch a file. So, with branches, each time you create a view, you only get one specific version of the same file, depending on the config spec of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simply done

Check out parent folder
Move element you wish to duplicate to appropriate location (not within the checked out parent folder)

Undo Checkout of parent folder

All the files get returned to the original folder with history and also the duplicate ones remain in the new location with the history too. Now each file can be checked out and changed individually